# why my .swf file show "undefine" word instead of text?

Tags: flash

when I view .swf file online it work gud but when I try to watch than file on my local drive it show "undefined" word instead of text and some of the text become useless word.I think it is because I don't have that font which site use.how to know which font site use?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a font issue. 'undefined' indicates a script problem. Your swf must be trying to load dynamic text, but not finding it from your local drive.

If you want to see what fonts are used, check the option to include a file size report in your FLA's publish settings.